# How to Merge Columns in Rows in a Dataframe that fulfill a Condition, while deleting the Rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I dont think I can solve it with `groupby()` or `agg()` like in these ([Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum), [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46732760/merge-rows-pandas-dataframe-based-on-condition))'s.

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` that has one identifier column (`ID_Code`) and some information columns(`information 1` and `information 2`). I need to aggregate some of the identifiers. Meaning some have to be deleted and their information has to be added into specific other rows.

To illustrate my problem here is something I made up:

```
import pandas as pd

inp = [{'ID_Code':1,'information 1':list(x * 3 for x in range(2, 5)),'information 2':list(x / 3 for x in range(2, 5))},
       {'ID_Code':2,'information 1':list(x * 0.5 for x in range(2, 5)),'information 2':list(x / 2 for x in range(2, 5))},
       {'ID_Code':3,'information 1':list(x * 0.2 for x in range(25, 29)),'information 2':list(x / 1 for x in range(2, 5))},
       {'ID_Code':4,'information 1':list(x * 0.001 for x in range(102, 105)),'information 2':list(x / 12 for x in range(2, 5))},
       {'ID_Code':5,'information 1':list(x * 12 for x in range(15, 17)),'information 2':list(x / 24 for x in range(2, 5))},
       {'ID_Code':6,'information 1':list(x * 42 for x in range(2, 9)),'information 2':list(x / 48 for x in range(2, 5))},
       {'ID_Code':7,'information 1':list(x * 23 for x in range(1, 2)),'information 2':list(x / 96 for x in range(2, 5))},
       {'ID_Code':8,'information 1':list(x * 7.8 for x in range(8, 11)),'information 2':list(x / 124 for x in range(2, 5))}]

df = pd.DataFrame(inp)

print(df)
Out:
       ID_Code                                                    information 1   information 2
    0        1                                                       [6, 9, 12]   [0.6666666666666666, 1.0, 1.3333333333333333]
    1        2                                                  [1.0, 1.5, 2.0]   [1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
    2        3                              [5.0, 5.2, 5.4, 5.6000000000000005]   [2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
    3        4  [0.10200000000000001, 0.10300000000000001, 0.10400000000000001]   [0.16666666666666666, 0.25, 0.3333333333333333]
    4        5                                                       [180, 192]   [0.08333333333333333, 0.125, 0.16666666666666666]
    5        6                               [84, 126, 168, 210, 252, 294, 336]   [0.041666666666666664, 0.0625, 0.08333333333333333]
    6        7                                                             [23]   [0.041666666666666664, 0.0625, 0.08333333333333333]
    7        8                                               [62.4, 70.2, 78.0]   [0.016129032258064516, 0.024193548387096774, 0.03225806451612903]
```

What do I need to do, if I want to get rid of `ID_Code = 1` and store it's information in `ID_Code = 3`, and get rid of `ID_Code = 5` and `ID_Code = 7` and store that information in `ID_Code = 2`, so that the DataFrame looks like this:

```
   ID_Code                                                    information 1   information 2
0        2                                    [180, 192, 23, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]   [0.08333333333333333, 0.125, 0.16666666666666666, 0.041666666666666664, 0.0625, 0.08333333333333333, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
1        3                    [6, 9, 12, 5.0, 5.2, 5.4, 5.6000000000000005]   [2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
2        4  [0.10200000000000001, 0.10300000000000001, 0.10400000000000001]   [0.6666666666666666, 1.0, 1.3333333333333333, 0.16666666666666666, 0.25, 0.3333333333333333]
3        6                               [84, 126, 168, 210, 252, 294, 336]   [0.041666666666666664, 0.0625, 0.08333333333333333]
4        8                                               [62.4, 70.2, 78.0]   [0.016129032258064516, 0.024193548387096774, 0.03225806451612903]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could conditionally change your `df['ID_Code']`  then sum the columns.

```
col = 'ID_Code'
cond = [df[col].eq(1),
       df[col].isin([5,7])]

outputs = [3,2]

df[col] = np.select(cond,outputs,default=df[col])

df1 = df.groupby(col).sum()

print(df1)


                                             information 1  \
ID_Code                                                      
2                            [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 180, 192, 23]   
3            [6, 9, 12, 5.0, 5.2, 5.4, 5.6000000000000005]   
4        [0.10200000000000001, 0.10300000000000001, 0.1...   
6                       [84, 126, 168, 210, 252, 294, 336]   
8                                       [62.4, 70.2, 78.0]   

                                             information 2  
ID_Code                                                     
2        [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 0.08333333333333333, 0.125, 0....  
3        [0.6666666666666666, 1.0, 1.3333333333333333, ...  
4          [0.16666666666666666, 0.25, 0.3333333333333333]  
6        [0.041666666666666664, 0.0625, 0.0833333333333...  
8        [0.016129032258064516, 0.024193548387096774, 0...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `ID_Code` as index, and update with list comprehension:

```
df=df.set_index('ID_Code')
df.loc[3] = [x+y for x,y in zip(df.loc[1], df.loc[3])]
df = df.drop(1)
```

Comment: does this need updated python ? doesn't update for me when i run it

Comment: @Datanovice should work with most version of Python/Pandas.