# Merge columns in rows in a adapted Dataframe that fulfill a condition, while deleting the rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Background Information**

This question is closely related to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62431862/how-to-merge-columns-in-rows-in-a-dataframe-that-fulfill-a-condition-while-dele). Unfortunately while making up an general example it was not specific enough to be applied to my personal problem. That is why this question is more specific.

**Example - Code Snippet**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

inp = [{'ID_Code':1,'information 1':[10,22,44],'information 2':[1,0,1]},
       {'ID_Code':2,'information 1':[400,323],'information 2':[1,1]},
       {'ID_Code':2,'information 1':[243],'information 2':[0]},
       {'ID_Code':2,'information 1':[333,555],'information 2':[0]},
       {'ID_Code':3,'information 1':[12,27,43,54],'information 2':[1,0,1,1]},
       {'ID_Code':3,'information 1':[31,42,13,14],'information 2':[1,0,0,0]},
       {'ID_Code':3,'information 1':[14,24,34,14],'information 2':[1,0,1,1]},
       {'ID_Code':4,'information 1':[15,25,33,44],'information 2':[0,0,0,1]},
       {'ID_Code':5,'information 1':[12,12,13,14],'information 2':[1,1,1,0]},
       {'ID_Code':5,'information 1':[12,12,13,24],'information 2':[1,0,1,1]},
       {'ID_Code':5,'information 1':[21,22,23,14],'information 2':[1,1,1,1]},
       {'ID_Code':6,'information 1':[10,12,23,4],'information 2':[1,0,1,0]},
       {'ID_Code':7,'information 1':[112,212,143,124],'information 2':[0,0,0,0]},
       {'ID_Code':7,'information 1':[211,321],'information 2':[1]},
       {'ID_Code':7,'information 1':[431],'information 2':[1,0]},
       {'ID_Code':8,'information 1':[1,2,3,4],'information 2':[1,0,0,1]}]


df = pd.DataFrame(inp)

df1=df.groupby("ID_Code")["information 1"].apply(list).to_frame()
df2=df.groupby("ID_Code")["information 2"].apply(list).to_frame()
df3=pd.concat([df1, df2],axis=1, sort=False)
```

**The Output**

```
ID_Code    information 1                                            information 2
1          [[10, 22, 44]]                                           [[1, 0, 1]]
2          [[400, 323], [243], [333, 555]]                          [[1, 1], [0], [0]]
3          [[12, 27, 43, 54], [31, 42, 13, 14], [14, 24, 34, 14]]   [[1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1]]
4          [[15, 25, 33, 44]]                                       [[0, 0, 0, 1]]
5          [[12, 12, 13, 14], [12, 12, 13, 24], [21, 22, 23, 14]]   [[1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
6          [[10, 12, 23, 4]]                                        [[1, 0, 1, 0]]
7          [[112, 212, 143, 124], [211, 321], [431]]                [[0, 0, 0, 0], [1], [1, 0]]
8          [[1, 2, 3, 4]]                                           [[1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Where ID_Code is no longer a column but the index. Which is the problem that I hadn't specified in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62431862/how-to-merge-columns-in-rows-in-a-dataframe-that-fulfill-a-condition-while-dele).

**The Task**

With the given Dataframe "df3", to get rid of ID_Code = 1 and store its information in ID_Code = 3, and get rid of ID_Code = 5 and ID_Code = 7 and store that information in ID_Code = 2, so that the DataFrame looks like this:

```
ID_Code    information 1                                                                                                                       information 2
2          [[400, 323], [243], [333, 555], [12, 12, 13, 14], [12, 12, 13, 24], [21, 22, 23, 14], [112, 212, 143, 124], [211, 321], [431]]     [[1, 1], [0], [0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1], [1, 0]]
3          [[12, 27, 43, 54], [31, 42, 13, 14], [14, 24, 34, 14], [10, 22, 44]]                                                               [[1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
4          [[15, 25, 33, 44]]                                                                                                                 [[0, 0, 0, 1]]
6          [[10, 12, 23, 4]]                                                                                                                  [[1, 0, 1, 0]]
8          [[1, 2, 3, 4]]                                                                                                                     [[1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

It would be a huge help, if someone could help me solve this.

Comment: What's the pattern in selecting the ID and storing its information in another ID?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no pattern, in my original Dataset I have ~15 "ID's" that need to be deleted and the information restored in ID's that are somewhat "related" to the ones deleted. I had to manually choose the most related ID's as well. That is why it needs to be a code, that can specifically choose a row to extract the information and delete and a row where the information has to be added into.

Comment: @RobertRedisch How do you select the row with ID_Code=1 to be added to the row with ID_Code=3? What is the logic behind it?

Comment: As I've written before, there is no rule which decides which ones have to be merged, I have to manually select it in my original dataset. The column, that I've called ID_Code here, has Codes that are related to each other. An example would be postcodes. You could imagine that I need to delete some postcodes for some reason, and I have to add the information to a postcode which is geographically close by, and therefore has to be selected by hand. In short: I need to be able to specifically choose a row to extract and delete the information, and a row where the information has to be added into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me with the answer given by [Datanovice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9375102/datanovice) from the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62431862/how-to-merge-columns-in-rows-in-a-dataframe-that-fulfill-a-condition-while-dele) with some changes to the indexing.

As the Question states, the problem lies in the `'ID_Code'` being an Index rather than a column. So my solution involves adding a column with the **unique ID_Code's**. For that I found two possible approaches.

**Solution 1**

Using `.unique()` in combination with `pd.Dataframe()` as .unique() returns a numpy.ndarray which has to be converted to a Dataframe again.

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame(df['ID_Code'].unique(),columns=['ID_Code'],index=df['ID_Code'].unique())
df5 = pd.concat([df4,df3],axis=1)
col = 'ID_Code'
cond = [df5[col].eq(1),
       df5[col].isin([5,7])]

outputs = [3,2]

df5[col] = np.select(cond,outputs,default=df5[col])

df6 = df5.groupby(col).sum()
```

**Solution 2**

Using `.reset_index()` to move the ID_Code out of the index into a seperate column.

```
df3 = df3.reset_index()
col = 'ID_Code'
cond = [df3[col].eq(1),
       df3[col].isin([5,7])]

outputs = [3,2]

df3[col] = np.select(cond,outputs,default=df3[col])

df4 = df3.groupby(col).sum()
```