# Pandas dataframe merge rows based on overlap and intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am failly new with Pandas and I have a question about how to properly merge rows within my pandas datafame, based on the values of its columns.

I have a dataframe,  `df1`, which contains the following:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[["shoe", 4, 6, 0.110, 10],
                        ["bracelet", 22, 25, 0.115, 40],
                       ["belt", 2, 5, 0.120, 12],
                       ["socks", 1, 3, 0.422, 8],
                       ["scarf", 10, 12, 0.630, 6],
                       ["skirt", 4, 6, 0.9, 5],
                       ["bag", 9, 13, 1.131, 4],
                       ["watch", 1, 4, 1.8, 5],
                       ["sweater", 4, 5, 5.5, 14],
                       ["jeans", 1, 6, 5.6, 14]],
                    columns=['item','low','high','time', 'price'])
df1
    item         low    high    time    price
0   shoe         4      6       0.110   10
1   bracelet     22     25      0.115   40
2   belt         2      5       0.120   12
3   socks        1      3       0.422   8
4   scarf        10     12      0.630   6
5   skirt        4      6       0.9     5
6   bag          9      13      1.131   4
7   watch        1      4       1.8     5
8   sweater      4      5       5.500   14
9   jeans        1      6       5.600   14
```

I would like to merge these rows based on the values in `['low', 'high', 'time', 'price']` and keep track of `item`.
I would like to merge rows where consecutive rows are less than `1` (e.g. seconds) apart based on the `time` column. Based on this criteria I want to merge rows `0 -- 7`. **But**, I only want actually merge them when there is an overlap between the range of `['low', 'high']`. Based on this `socks`, `belt`, `shoe`, `skirt` and `watch` get merged together because they have ranges (1,3), (2,5), (4,6), (4,6), (1,4) and `bracelet` does not get merged with other rows.

Of the rows that are about to be merge together, I would like to keep the `item`, `time` and `price` for the row that had the highest `price`. I would also like to update `low` and `high` such that it fully the covers the entire range of the merged rows. Finally, I would like two new columns `time_min` and `time_max` that will indicate the total time range of the merge columns. If rows that are to be merged have the same `price`, take the one with the lowest `time` (there will not be rows with exactly the same `time` and `price`).

Based on these rules I would expect the following dataframe, `df2`:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[["belt", 2, 6, 0.120, 12, 0.110, 0.422],
                         ["bracelet", 22, 25, 0.115, 10, 0.115, 0.115],
                         ["scarf", 9, 13, 0.130, 6, 0.630, 1.131],
                         ["sweater", 1, 6, 5.5, 14, 5.5, 5.6]],
                   columns=['item','low','high','time', 'price', 'time_min', 'time_max'])
df2
    item        low high    time    price   time_min    time_max
0   belt        2   6       0.120   12      0.110       1.8
1   bracelet    22  25      0.115   10      0.115       0.115
2   scarf       9   13      0.130   6       0.630       1.131
3   sweater     1   6       5.500   14      5.500       5.600
```

I have looked at the Q&A as provided by: [merge rows pandas dataframe based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46732760/merge-rows-pandas-dataframe-based-on-condition), but in that question they only merge on (in this case) `['low', 'high']` and some information that I would need to retain is lost.

Comment: What does _where consecutive rows are less than 1 (e.g. seconds) apart_ exactly mean? E.g. you could have consecutive `time`s like `0.5, 1.4, 2.3`: Would they meet the requirement?

Comment: Hi Timus, yes that would meet the requirement. I have edited the example dataframe which now better illustrates such a scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt:

```
def consolidate(sdf):
    low_high_sorted = sdf[['low', 'high']].sort_values(['low', 'high'])
    grouping = pd.Series(0, index=low_high_sorted.index)
    group, group_max = 0, low_high_sorted.high.iat[0]
    for i, low, high in low_high_sorted.iloc[1:, :].itertuples():
        if low <= group_max:
            group_max = max(group_max, high)
        else:
            group += 1
            group_max = high
        grouping.at[i] = group

    return sdf.groupby(grouping).agg(
        i_max=('price', lambda x: x.idxmax()),
        low=('low', 'min'), high=('high', 'max'), price=('price', 'max'),
        time_min=('time', 'min'), time_max=('time', 'max') 
    )

df2 = (
    df1.groupby(((df1.time - df1.time.shift()) >= 1.).cumsum())
       .apply(consolidate)
       .merge(df1.item, left_on='i_max', right_index=True, how='left')
       .drop(columns='i_max')
       .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Result:

```
   low  high  price  time_min  time_max      item
0    1     6     12     0.110     1.800      belt
1    9    13      6     0.630     1.131     scarf
2   22    25     40     0.115     0.115  bracelet
3    1     6     14     5.500     5.600   sweater
```

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to build the `grouping` series in `consolidate` by Pandas methods.

---

**1. Step**: Grouping `df1` to get the groups determined by the `time` column. Checking if time difference between time and time in the row before is greater or equal than `1.` and then cumsumming over the resulting column (`False`/`True` = `0`/ `1`):

```py
    time  time_diff_ge_1  cumsum
0  0.110           False       0
1  0.115           False       0
2  0.120           False       0
3  0.422           False       0
4  0.630           False       0
5  0.900           False       0
6  1.131           False       0
7  1.800           False       0
8  5.500            True       1
9  5.600           False       1
```

(I should have used `df1.time.diff()` instead of `df1.time - df1.time.shift()`.)

**2. Step**: [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html)-ing `consolidate` over the first grouping. Inside of it second grouping over the connected intervalls. To find the connections: Sorting `low`- and `high`-column to allow for a linear processing afterwards:

```py
   low  high
3    1     3
7    1     4
2    2     5
0    4     6
5    4     6
6    9    13
4   10    12
1   22    25
```

(Actually, sorting only over `low` would be enough: `sdf[['low', 'high']].sort_values('low')`.) For finding the connection-groups it's now enough to check if `low` is less or equal to the the current groups `high`-max. If that's not the case a new connection-group starts.

```py
   low  high  grouping
3    1     3         0
7    1     4         0
2    2     5         0
0    4     6         0
5    4     6         0
6    9    13         1
4   10    12         1
1   22    25         2
```

Using a `pd.Series` as grouping has a nice effect: The indices will be aligned, which essentially makes it a mapping *index -> grouping value*, so the order of the indeces doesn't matter. See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

> ... If a dict or Series is passed, the Series or dict VALUES will be used to determine the groups (the Series’ values are first aligned; see `.align()` method).

**3. Step**: Aggregating over the resulting groups into one line by [`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html). `agg`-logic:

```
new_column_name=(used_column, aggregating_function)
```

Small detour to get the `item` that corresponds to the highest `price`: Fetching here only the corresponding index `i_max` via [`.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html). ([`methodcaller`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) would be an alternative to the `lambda`-function: `methodcaller('idxmax')`.)

**4. Step**: [`.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)-ing the result along `i_max`-`index` with `df1.item` to get the `item`s that correspond to the `i_max`es, and then dropping the `i_max` column afterwards.

Comment: Thank you very much Timus! I think this is an excellent attempt.

Comment: @scientist Thanks! I'm still thinking about the grouping ... :)

Comment: Hi Timus, if you have the time and are willing to help me, could you explain the code you posted or add some comments to it. I think I know what you are doing, but would be good to make sure I for 100% know what you are doing.

Comment: @scientist Will do, this evening. (Should have done that in the first place, it's bad style to answer without explanations.)

Comment: @scientist I've added some explanations. Please let me know if it isn't clear enough and/or you find an error!

Comment: Hi Timus, thank you very much for the explanation. I totally understand what happens now. So far I have not found any errors using my actual data. Thanks again!